# How do I hide the VR Mode / Goggles icon for A-Frame?

Tags: aframe, webvr

In the bottom right corner, by default, is a Goggles icon that when clicked, enters VR or fullscreen (if no headset). How do I hide this so I can add my own UI, or disable VR altogether?

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can disable the `vr-mode-ui` component:

`<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">`

Learn more about the `vr-mode-ui` component [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/vr-mode-ui.html).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, I just wanted to share this since I had the same issue:
In the version 1.5.0 of A-frame, this attribute is not called `vr-mode-ui` anymore, but `xr-mode-ui`

So the code is

`<a-scene xr-mode-ui="enabled: false">`

[Here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/xr-mode-ui.md)'s the newest documentation.